# How to assign unique IDs to inputs from an input form

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, http-delete

I know this is probably a dumb question, but I can't figure it out:(

I have an input-form:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="customSubmit">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="newUser.name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <label>E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" v-model="newUser.email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email-Address">
    <label>Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="number" v-model="newUser.number" id="number" placeholder="Your mobile number" @keyup.enter="customSubmit">
        
</form>
<button type="button" class=buttonSignup @click="customSubmit">Submit</button>
```

The Data gets processed and is fetched to a little `nodeJS`-Server with the following function:

```js
customSubmit(){
    //Check ob alle Felder gefüllt sind
    if(document.getElementById('name').value === ''){return}
    if(document.getElementById('email').value === ''){return}
    if(document.getElementById('number').value === ''){return}
    //POST to API
    const user = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({newUser: this.newUser})
    };
                
    fetch("http://localhost:3080/api/user", user)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));

    this.pushFunction(); //GET-Request to view the data

    this.clearForm();
}
```

However, to be able to also send `DELETE`-Request, I need to assign unique ID's to each entry within the `customSubmit()`-function.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Also please ignore the german comments in the code-snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your node server create an entry and send back a unique id as a response to the POST request you are sending.

The ID can be the one issued by the database (depending on which db you are using) and then it'll be part of the `data` object returned from the `fetch`.

Comment: Thanks, worked out fine, after some fiddeling around